# 'super' object has no attribute '__eq__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, super, python-object

When I try to override the magic method `__eq__`, and use `super` to access the base method found in `object`, I get an error. There's no way this is a bug, but it sure feels like one:

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return super(A, self).__eq__(other)
A() == 0

# raises AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__eq__'
```

This is unintuitive because `object.__eq__` exists, but for `class A(object): pass` it doesn't. If I'm not mistaken `__eq__` resorts to an `is` check, so that may be the workaround here, but using `is` instead of `super` isn't mixin friendly. Going that route is ok in my case, but in others it might not be.

Any suggestions, or info on why `__eq__` works this way would be great.

Comment: The error is raised in 2.7 but not raised in 3.5

Comment: No, `object` does not support `__eq__` on **instances** ... try `object().__eq__`, it will raise an `AttributeError` ...  instead `object.__eq__ is (probably) a classmethod for checking if types are identical (eg `object.__eq__(object)`)

Comment: @donkopotamus: That will not compare your object with `other`; it will compare a newly-created "blank" object with `other`.

Comment: @BrenBarn the point I was making is that `object().__eq__` doesn't even work, it will raise an attribute error (edited to make it clear)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in Will's answer, `object()` does not actually implement `__eq__` at all for instances (in python 2.7).

You are being deceived by the fact that `object.__eq__` exists into believing it must be a method that checks if **instances** of object are equal

Instead, `object.__eq__` is actually a class method, inherited from `type`, that is used to check if types are equal.

That is, to handle expressions such as `object == int` and `object == object`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `object()` doesn't actually implement an `__eq__()`. The "default" here would be:

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self is other:
            return True

        return self == other
```

But, if what you're attempting had worked, you would actually be checking whether the `self` instance of the parent class equaled `other`. And, it's the same object (`self`), so it would. So the closest equivalent of your code would actually be:

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self is other:
            return True

        return super(A, self) == other
```

Comment: As I commented on a previously-deleted answer, your second example does not inherit the default behavior, since if you do `x = A()`, then `x == x` returns False.  (Your first example causes infinite recursion.)